# Agora.io multiple Rooms for veideochat

Tags: javascript, agora.io, videochat

I've managed to create a simple Agora Videochat on my hosting, works fine. For this purpose I've created an account by agora.io to get an App ID and a token for this videochat.

But is there an option to make multiple rooms for video calls, like:

```
www.mysite.com/room1 
www.mysite.com/room2
www.mysite.com/room3
```

and so on?

Do I have to create multiple projects in Agora account to use unique App IDs for every room?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one project can contain multiple rooms with unique room name.

All you have to do is to manage room name to be unique.